# Mysterious loss of weight

Tags: lateral-thinking, story

Now an entry into Fortnightly Topic Challenge #41: Short and Sweet

A man enters a room and presses a button. Within seconds he loses 20 lbs body weight. How did he lose the weight?

Comment: "Lateral Thinking" Oh! I get it!

Comment: Nitpick: He loses 20 lbf. His mass stays the same.

Comment: He’s carrying 20 pounds of groceries in a bag, which he coincidentally drops on the floor a few seconds after pressing a completely unrelated button.

Comment: @ohno lb is a unit of weight (as well as unit of mass), and the question says he loses weight.

Comment: @armb Most technically, the pound is always a unit of force, and the unit of mass is the slug.

Comment: a very enthousiastic blood donor perhaps? :P

Comment: The pound is also a unit of currency.

Comment: @chrylis The pound is _not_ always a unit of force. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foot%E2%80%93pound%E2%80%93second_system#Pound_as_mass_unit

Comment: You guys are talking past each other because there's at least 5 or 6 different types of pounds (in modern usage; historically, there were even more). Some of these measure mass, and some of them, weight.

Comment: This wasn't asked during the fortnightlly challenge- I don't think it's a valid submission.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

He entered

> an elevator and pressed the down button. The downward acceleration from the elevator reduces his apparent weight.

Comment: Doing the math for the average weight of 136lbs(62kg), acceleration of the elevator must be about -1.5 m/s^2.  To put that in context, the average acceleration of an elevator is around -0.64 m/s^2.

Comment: lbs is mass, not weight... but blame it on the question.

Comment: @vsz: Nope.  lbs is weight, not mass.  You have it backward.  "slugs" are the unit of mass in the Imperial system.

Comment: Does he add 20 lbf when the elevator goes up? Of course

Comment: The pound is a unit of both mass and force.
The poundal is unambiguously a unit of force, which will give a mass of one pound an acceleration of one foot per second per second.
The slug is unambiguously a unit of mass, which will be accelerated at one foot per second per second by a one pound force.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foot%E2%80%93pound%E2%80%93second_system#Variants

Comment: @Beska : No, lbs, as currently legally defined, is mass. It's lbf which is force.

Comment: Are there any lifts/elevators that accelerate for several seconds? As soon as the lift ceases acceleration (which usually is sooner than "within seconds"), their normal weight is back...

Comment: Weight is a vector force, generally expressed as Newtons in a particular direction. Elevator acceleration varies by country. -1.5 m/s^2 is not unreasonable. Trap door water slides may give more. The room could also be a cockpit.

Comment: @vsz The legal definition would be relevant if this was a court of law. Usually weight means mass in legal contexts but force in engineering contexts (https://www.quora.com/Is-lb-a-unit-of-mass-or-force). The question mentions weight. It could be interpreted either way.

Comment: @DavidStarkey or the man is 306.4577012175 pounds. Perhaps he needs to lose some mass rather than weight.

Comment: @Edheldil: As soon as the acceleration is reached, it counts as having happened “within seconds”. It’s okay if the pounds also come back within seconds.

Answer (score 75):

Since it's tagged 'lateral-thinking', an alternative that blatantly ignores the question's title is that:

> The man is in the UK, and he just pressed 'OK' button to confirm a £20 purchase

Comment: I thought of this first, but it specifies "weight" in the question, so this answer is invalid

Comment: :jedi-hand-wave: Let's just call that a 'Financial Burden' then :P

Comment: "Pounds" is abbreviated as "lbs.," which is never used for the currency.

Comment: However, did you know that the "£" symbol and the "lbs." abbreviation both have the same origin? They both essentially mean Libras (scales, used for measuring weight).

Comment: Isn't this less "Lateral thinking" and more "Vertical thinking" ?

Comment: Isn't the descent of the elevator the more vertical of the thought processes? :P

Comment: @Quintec Because the Lift is faster than the Escalator, so he lost the *wait*.  ;¬)

Comment: OP should have used kilo instead.

Comment: @Mixxiphoid - No, because you don't lose mass (kg) when the elevator begins its descent, only apparent weight - and using Newtons as a measure of weight would be an odd choice for the puzzle, too.

Comment: @DaveB I don't get it, how would the question be any different if it was 10 kg, instead of 20lbs? They both represent mass, right?

Comment: Excellent question!  In our everyday lives, mass and weight seem like the same thing, but they're actually different.  Mass is a measure of an object's inertia, or "how much energy does it take to accelerate this thing?".  Weight is a measure of force, or "How hard does this thing push against that other thing?".  When measuring these while standing still in Earth's gravity well, they're strongly related - the force exerted by you on whatever you're standing on is proportional to your mass (and the mass of the planet and how far away you are from its centre of mass) ...

Comment: ... But if you are accelerating upwards or downwards (or if you go to a different planet), the force that you're exerting on whatever you're standing on will be different even though you are still made of the exact same mass - the number and type of atoms doesn't change.   So when the elevator starts going down, the force you're exerting on the floor of the elevator is reduced slightly since the floor is 'falling' just a little bit with you.  However, once the speed of the elevator becomes constant again, the forces are again balanced and the force you exert on the floor goes back to normal

Comment: So to make a long response short, using kilograms instead of pounds would require that the person in the riddle actually loses mass - that is, to cause some significant number of atoms to disappear or no longer be considered part of their body.  However, to lose weight we just need to reduce the force that is being exerted by the existing mass, and we can do _that_ in much less traumatic ways.

Comment: Hmm. Actually, reading the comments in the other answer, it sounds like I may have been under some misconceptions as well - when learning about the imperial system, I was always told that pounds was the base Imperial unit for weight - but apparently the term is ambiguous and there are different abbreviations that carry different meanings/connotations (!)  ... That Imperial system is _weird_

Comment: Eventually, using ***kilo*** as is could be interpreted both **kilo*gram*** (mass) or **kilo*Newton*** (force) - or **kilo*anything*** (1.000 anything)

Comment: Right, but the abbreviation kg (and not _just_ *k*) would still be used, and that would unambiguously refers to only one of those.

Comment: Also, I can't believe that this answer, which I cheekily acknowledge is a wrong answer in the first line, currently has more positive votes than the right one

Comment: Nice try but see the question it is - How did he lose the WEIGHT?

Comment: @DaveB It's not wrong, from a certain point of view.

Comment: @Quark-epoch- I acknowledge that the answer is wrong multiple times and that this was just a cheeky response for a laugh. :) The 'WEIGHT' part is addressed (or at least hand-waved) in the first two comments.

Answer (score 47):

> He presses the button to start a machine. It catastrophically fails within seconds and takes off the lower part of his leg, which weighed 20 lbs.

Comment: Should I be concerned this was my first thought too?

Comment: Somewhat along those lines would be someone in one of the Saw movies going to the next room and, well... lets just say traps and stuff.

Comment: It is a little too much deviation from the story

Answer (score 21):

For an answer which exactly fits the question and the OP's clarifications...

> He is wearing a diver's weight belt with a quick-release catch.

Answer (score 18):

He is:

> Holding a 20 lbs of iron.  The button activates a **very** powerful magnet.

Or:

> In a room with some sort of anti-gravity (or, rather, gravity manipulating) feature.  Just something that would slightly adjust the gravitational constant to make you lighter.

Comment: no he loses 20 lb body weight

Comment: Probably should specify that in the question :-)

Comment: well, rot13(va nagv-tenivgl ur jbhyq ybfr nyy uvf obql jrvtug abg whfg 20 yof naq 20 yof pna'g or uvf obql jrvtug)

Comment: what is he holding?

Comment: He had a metal leg?

Comment: If the device mentioned in your first proposal is strong enough (extremely!), just the hemoglobin in the blood should be enough.

Answer (score 16):

A somewhat less morbid variant of an answer that's been posted a few times:

> He has a prosthetic leg that weighs 20 pounds, and the button releases its clasp.

Comment: that is dammed clever. good one!

Comment: Why doesn't this answer have more upvotes?

Answer (score 7):

> The man previously lost 20lbs and without knowing this he came to check his weight on a weight machine and pressed button to check his weight apparently in seconds the result popped up showing he lost 20lbs, looks very natural and correct answer ! dont ask me exactly how he lost 20 lbs :-)

Answer (score 5):

I know this already has a correct answer, but I'd like to offer an alternative:

> The man works as a stocker and is holding 20lbs worth of cardboard. He enters the back room where he puts the cardboard in a baler and crushes it with the push of a button.

Comment: According to my calculations, 20 lbs of cardboard is 152 square meters of cardboard, approximately a 12 by 12 meter piece of cardboard. No matter how you fold it, that'll be impossible to hold by one man.

Comment: He loses 20 lbs BODY WEIGHT

Answer (score 5):

> It was an air lock of a submarine and filled the chamber with water, the buoyancy reduces his weight by 20 lbs.

or

> The button published a new law that vital organs are owned by the government rather than the individual. He is no longer the legal owner of that weight.

or

> The man was head of the International Committee for Weights and Measures and the button was publishing a new heavier definition of the pound.

Answer (score 4):

> He walked into a Star Trek transporter (or similar) and transported himself to a planet where gravity was less strong.

Answer (score 4):

The button...

> ... triggers a guillotine which chops a leg off (apparently ~20lb for an adult male)

Answer (score 4):

A very

## Lateral Thinking

type answer. You say that the man loses 20 lbs of body weight within seconds - but

> you don't say *how many* seconds.

It *could* be

> several billion seconds

or even just

> 7,776,000 seconds, which is three months.

Consequently, the button was

> The doorbell in the lobby of his gym. (He goes to a very high-end gym.)

It's quite reasonable to lose 20 lbs of body weight

> in three months of working out (and eating right). The first step was ringing the bell.

Comment: that is too lateral a thought to comprehend. This puzzle is too broad to be honest. I thought it would be closed for being too broad in the beginning but then it was unusually successful

Comment: @Quark-epoch I think it was close to being closed, but the answer you were looking for was fairly obvious IMO

Comment: Yeah, I agree, I thought the same as this is such an absurd question. It was one of my first.

Answer (score 3):

Upon pressing the button,

> The entire room starts to accelerate downwards (for example, he is inside the lift) at an acceleration of **a**

So

> Given that his original weight is Mg - Ma = 20lbs, we calculate the a given his mass M.

Comment: Nice answer, but next time you should really put your answers in spoilers :D

Answer (score 3):

Simple, the man pressed

> the buzzer on his door and let in a cleptomaniac bodybuilder who proceeded to steal his 20lb dumbbell.
>  He lost his weight because he's too trusting of other people.

Answer (score 3):

> The man traveled to another planet where the gravity is less than his spacecraft. he
>  opened the door of spacecraft and loss 20lbs of his weight. (assuming he created the room to adjust the gravity of that planet)

or

> the man was using jetpack when he pressed the button he lost 20 lbs of
>  his weight. ( he was trying to practice to use jetpack inside the big room of enough space and it can also be water jet)

or

> man was a pilot when his plane takeoff he lost 20lbs of weight. ( he may enter the pilot room and press the take-off button and lose 20lbs weight )

or

> man was carrying something attached to him with an electronic device when he pressed the button he lost 20lbs of weight because the luggage dropped.

Comment: Unfortunately, not the answer I was expecting but good try. +1

Answer (score 2):

My first thought was:

> He entered an elevator and pushed a button, causing the elevator to go down.  The acceleration downwards is credited with making the man 20 pounds lighter, if only for a brief moment.

Then I thought of this:

> If "lbs" stands for British pounds, then the man could have been at a gambling casino.  He could have bet twenty pounds on red in a game of electronic roulette.  When he pushed a button, the roulette ball landed on black, causing the man to lose his 20 pounds.

Thinking about it some more, I thought:

> If the twenty pounds are truly weight, then the man could have simply been separated from something on his person.  This could be an arm or a leg (separated by, oh, let's say a button-activated-spring-loaded-sawblade), or just something he was carrying.  Maybe he was a delivery man delivering a 20 lb. package that was ordered on-line.  He rings the doorbell, then within seconds a spring-loaded-saw... I mean, a grateful customer takes the 20 lb. package from the delivery man.

But then I thought some more, and I came up with:

> Maybe he bought a collection of Richard Simmons' "Sweatin' to the Oldies" videos (I've seen some for around that price).  I can't really explain how he'd lose so much weight "within seconds," unless I reinterpret "seconds" to mean "going back for seconds" (often heard when eating a meal).  Maybe he liked the videos so much, he exercised a second time, or managed to lose enough weight despite having more portions of food.

Comment: I like the thinking. The first part is already said but the second and fourth parts are intriguing

Answer (score 2):

> The button was connected to explosives hidden in [this](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Berlin_schoeneberg_innsbrucker_01.11.2012_16-27-49.jpg), [this](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:MuensterLBSWest.jpg), [this](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:LSBStuttgart_2012-09.jpg) and seventeen more such buildings. When he presses the button, the twenty [LBS](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landesbausparkasse) are gone.

Answer (score 2):

> He entered a vertical wind tunnel which got up to speed slowly as he stood there after pressing the button

Answer (score -1):

> He enters lift, presses the button downwards. Psuedo acceleration upwards works here against gravity and weight measured is less now.
>
>  Let M be his mass and mg be weight before (outside lift)
>  Losing 20 lbs-
>  Pseudo acceleration is (Mg-20)/M unit length per square unit time

Comment: Exact same solution was already posted by Quintec. In addition please not to reveal spoilers by using `>!` at the beginning of a paragraph.

Comment: I didn't see the response. Just the question. And I also gave the equations, so it's not the exact same.