# Mysterious loss revamped

Tags: situation

This is a revamped version of my puzzle
[Mysterious loss of weight](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/72865/mysterious-loss-of-weight)
. I plan to make a series of puzzles on mysterious loss of ... say a number.

A man went into a black room full of white papers lying around him. He presses a button. All the papers rise and he also loses one of his documents lying on the ground

How did it happen?

**HINT 1 :**

> I have not included the link to the last puzzle for no reason

Comment: Does the man fly as well?

Comment: rot13(fbzrjung)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is it

> Elevator ? 
>  
>  The man was on the rooftop 
>  The button he push is open door button
>  All the papers rise because of the wind 
>  and one of them is of course, carried by the wind

Comment: I wanted this answer only. That is the very reason I included the link to my previous puzzle in this one . Well done . @Vent. Excellent.

Answer (score 3):

This seems way too obvious, but ...

> The button was the "On" button to a fan. He turned the fan on and the papers were all blown around the room.

Comment: But there was also a paper which was loosely held in his hand. It wont blow away with the sheer force of a fan. Try doing it in real life. Btw well tried

Comment: If you've never had anything blow out of your hand (especially if its "loosely held", you're not using a big enough fan.  :)

Comment: I must tweak the question

Comment: @Quark-epoch not sure that is a good edit as it invalidates a posted answer.

Comment: @Pugmonkey I will give your answer right if I do not get the answer I am expecting within 4 to 5 days.

Comment: @Barker The edit doesn't seem to invalidate any answers. Seems fine to me.

Comment: I gave the bounty to this answer as it was the right answer but not the one I expected. Well done @Pugmonkey

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to my other answer:

> When the man presses the button, the room fills with water, causing the paper to float to the top of the water. The man rises somewhat as well. As for the lost document, it might have been too heavy to float and sank to the bottom.

Comment: Hm I would think this to be the most likely option were it not for the detail that the room is black, which this answer does not mention.

Comment: It's.... a very dark pool.

Answer (score 1):

Crazy idea:

> The man walked into an industrial incinerator room, for example [like this](https://youtu.be/nYnkYuJjPy0?t=65s).  He had thrown in a bunch of papers and documents he wanted to incinerate.  Pressing the button started the incinerator, and the papers started burning and flying into the air (the man exited the room before it got too hot).

Second crazy idea:

> The man enters the cargo hold of an aircraft.  Inside are [propaganda leaflets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airborne_leaflet_propaganda).  He presses a button which opens the cargo door, and the leaflets blow out of the plane and land on the ground below.

Comment: The room is black. I guess cargo holds are white

Answer (score 1):

> The man was in a rocket cockpit (not sure about the technical term but still you get it.) The button was the blast-off button, and then at a weightless position, the papers fly around the room with the man somehow (according to OP’s comment in one of the other answers).

Answer (score 1):

My answer is:

> Darkroom is used by photographers to make photographs with photographic films. So when he presses a button, maybe he opens a window or door. Through with wind and light came inside. The wind rises all the paper which is used for photographs, the one he already prints ruined due to come in contact of the light.

Answer (score 0):

I suck at solving puzzles, but here goes:

> The room is a dark room for photo development, and the white papers are photos. When he presses the button, the photos (clearly attached to some mechanical arm) rise from the solution.

Comment: I have mentioned papers lying on the ground